# Make batch omit lines from a file

Tags: batch-file, sha256

I'm creating a batch fingerprinter, and I'm using a mix of SystemInfo and IpConfig to get a unique sha256 hash for a computer, the problem is i the systeminfo output there are things like boot time and others that change every time, and i need a way of omitting them before i generate the hash.
my current whole code is:

```
@echo off
systeminfo >>fingerprint.txt
echo - - - - - - - - - - - - >> fingerprint.txt
ipconfig >>fingerprint.txt
:: Here i want to have the omitter
powershell Get-FileHash fingerprint.txt -Algorithm SHA256 > comphash.txt
pause
```

Comment: Both the `FIND` and `FINDSTR` commands have a `/V` option which states: **Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.**

Comment: I've never heard of such a ridiculous way of performing such a task. To begin with `systeminfo` is probably the slowest command you could use, and will output far too much irrelevant information. Much of the information it provides is dynamic or easily reconfigured, and is therefore pointless. I would advise that you forget about getting help with your current code, and instead research which 'computer' hardware/software information to consider using instead. This site is not appropriate however for telling you what that is, and is likely better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Like pretty much all information about your computer, the computer's unique identifier can be found in `wmic`. In this case, it's the `UUID` property of the `csproduct` class, which handles computer system product information from SMBIOS.

`wmic` has some extra carriage returns at the end of the data so there's a bit of tweaking that needs to be done before you can just run it through a `for /f` loop like a normal command, but it will look like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('wmic csproduct get UUID /value ^| find "="') do set %%A
```

This will have the `wmic` command output its data in the format `UUID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` and then set the UUID to a variable called `%UUID%`, using `find` to look for the `=` and removing the excess carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer thanks to Squashman, final code in case someone wants to use it is:

```
@echo off
color 33
systeminfo | find "Domain:" /v | find "System" /v | find "Virtual" /v | find "Available" /v >> fingerprint.txt
echo Your computers unique fingerprint: >> finalhash.txt
powershell Get-FileHash fingerprint.txt -Algorithm SHA256 >> finalhash.txt
del fingerprint.txt
start finalhash.txt
pause
```

Comment: What happens when a new hotfix is added? the fingerprint will change! What about changes in memory? What about changing the input language? etc. This idea is completely wrong, please reconsider your entire methodology!

Comment: You could pare that all down to `findstr /v "Domain: System Virtual Available"`

Comment: I would also consider just using `CERTUTIL` to hash the file.  It will be much quicker then calling out to Powershell. Then you could filter out all the stuff you don't need from the `CERTUTIL` command as well. `certutil -hashfile fingerprint.txt SHA256|findstr /V /B "SHA256 CertUtil:"`

Comment: well using that `findstr` idea would remove the dynamic virtual memory changes, but, what if your end user changes their logon server, owner name, time zone? etc. What if they simply flash their BIOS firmware. What about  a non static IP Address, which can change at any time, or if they change their Gateway/DHCP Server?